# Why can I not do sum of a and b?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        boolean aValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        System.out.println(aValid);
        System.out.println("Enter Second number");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        boolean bValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        System.out.println(bValid);
        if(aValid && bValid){
            System.out.println("Sum of number is "+(a+b));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter integer number");
        }
    }
}
```

I try to get input of a and b and validate that a and b are integers. But it takes three input. It gives the sum of the first two numbers and gives the validity of the last two.

Answer (score 0):

you need to place check integer statements before taking input

```
boolean aValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        int a = sc.nextInt();
 boolean bValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this code makes the error fairly obvious. Some additional debug statements, running the code in debug or testing would also make it clear.

`Scanner.nextInt()` will throw an exception if it gets a non integer.
`Scanner.hasNextInt()` on the other hand returns a boolean value to warn you in advance whether it has an integer or not - it does not take the value from the Scanner.

This code has a couple of tiny corrections that will achieve the outcome you stated.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        boolean aValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        if (aValid) {
            a = sc.nextInt();
        } else {
            sc.next(); //Discard the non-integer input.fr
        }
        System.out.println(aValid);
        System.out.println("Enter Second number");
        boolean bValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        if (bValid) {
            b = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(bValid);
        if (aValid && bValid) {
            System.out.println("Sum of number is " + (a + b));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter integer numbers only");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        boolean aValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        if (aValid) {
            a = sc.nextInt();
        } 
        System.out.println(aValid);
        System.out.println("Enter Second number");
        boolean bValid = sc.hasNextInt();
        if (bValid) {
            b = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(bValid);
        if (aValid && bValid) {
            System.out.println("Sum of number is " + (a + b));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter integer numbers only");
        }
       
    }
}
```